# Is there a pattern for propagating configuration state down an object graph?

Tags: dependency-injection, circular-dependency, god-object

I'm trying to avoid creating a [monster class](http://www.schauderhaft.de/2013/03/17/dependency-antipatterns-god-node/), and I noticed a not-so-good pattern and was curious if anyone had any insight into this problem.

### Problem

`A` is complex. To avoid the "god object", some of the logic is pushed out into `B` and `C`.

A now serves as a [façade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). It depends on B and C.

```
A -> B
  -> C
```

However, A has configuration data that B and C need. So we have to keep the data in sync.

```
b.value1 = a.value1
b.value2 = a.value2

c.value1 = a.value1
c.value2 = a.value2
```

Also, B and C must convert the data to use it.

```
b.sum -> b.value1 + b.value2
b.doSomething -> b.sum() ...

c.sum -> c.value1 + c.value2
c.doSomethingElse -> c.sum() ...
```

To avoid writing duplicate code, we move these conversion methods back to A.

```
a.sum -> a.value1 + a.value2

b.doSomething -> a.sum() ...
c.doSomethingElse -> a.sum() ...
```

But this means B and C now depend on A, not just its data.

```
A -> B -> A
  -> C -> A
```

And this results in a circular dependency.

I've been studying dependency injection and the factory pattern, and these two ideas have solved a lot of problems, but I'm stumped on how to create an [object graph](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/) whose nodes are configurable at runtime. In other words, I need the ability to change the behavior of a specific node or group of nodes at runtime from the outside. What's the best way to propagate configuration state down an object graph?

### Edit

Having spent the last couple hours trying to formulate my thoughts into a question, I think I may have stumbled into a solution. I think what I need to do is create a configuration provider class `D` that gets passed into the nodes that depend on this information.

```
A -> B -> D
  -> C -> D
  -> D
```

D manages `value1` and `value2` and provides the `sum` method. D also has events that fire when value1 and value2 change so that dependent nodes (A, B and C) can respond to the change.

I think this solution works, but I wanted to post anyway in case there's a better solution. If this *is* the pattern I'm looking for, what is it called? The "provider" pattern? (Not to be confused with ASP.NET's [provider model](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/27/Providerisnotapattern/)!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for observer or mediator pattern. check it out on http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. After reading that article, I can see now that I had a mediator that got too large, and decided to split it out into a subject with multiple observers. My mistake was that I combined the subject with the facade (root) node. So that's why my idea to create a fourth node (D) works. It all makes sense now. Thanks!